# How to hide an IFrame on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm building a website which uses IFrames to play YouTube videos, instead of uploading the raw video as the host doesn't allow large file uploads and it seemed easier to use IFrames. However, how the website works is that when you press a button it opens a `div` over the top of the rest of the page, like a 'popup' I guess. So this requires that you can hide the IFrame when you close the div.

However, this doesn't work on mobile Chrome of Safari (for iOS10 latest versions). When I try to hide it, the rest of the div hides like normal but the video leaves an impression, as in you can't play it or click anything on the video but it prevents you clicking anything under the video also.

Has anyone encountered any issues like this? Can anyone suggest where my code is wrong?

The website is at http://citm.uk.tn/

Here's the code:

JavaScript:

```
function fillText(a){
  $('#body').load('html/' + a + '.html');
  b.style.height = '60vw';
  b.style.visibility = 'visible';
  ex.style.filter = 'blur(20px)';
  ex.style.WebkitFilter = 'blur(20px)';
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
function wipePop(){
  b.style.height = '0';
  b.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  ex.style.filter = 'none';
  ex.style.WebkitFilter = 'none';
  frame.style.height = '0';
  frame.style.opacity = '0';
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class='back' onclick='wipePop()'>Back To Home</a>
<iframe class='video' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXwYJyrKK5A?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="frame">
</iframe>
```

More HTML:

```
<div class='ex' id='ex'>
<div class='banner'><img src='images/full.png' class='full' id='im'></div>
<div class='buttons'><button class='cir' id='1'><img class='buttonimg' src='images/1.png'></button><button class='cir' id='2'><img class='buttonimg' src='images/2.png'></button><button class='cir' id='3'><img class='buttonimg' src='images/3.png'></button><button class='cir' id='4'><img class='buttonimg' src='images/4.png'></button></div>

<div class='videobanner'><button class='vidbanner_l' onclick="fillText('video1')"><img src='images/video.png'></button><button class='vidbanner' onclick="fillText('video2')"><img src='images/video2.png'></button></div>
<br><br><br>
</div>
<div class='body' id='body'>

</div>
```

I am using jQuery but anything using pure javascript would be prefered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a type error raise in the console.log when you click 'back to home'..try adding " var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');" inside your wipePop() function....

Comment: @repzero ah, thanks dude that fixed it :) didnt think to check the developer console since it worked fine on the pc 